# Knex Inserting Same Record Twice when Query Executed Asynchronously

Tags: node.js, postgresql, asynchronous, async-await, knex.js

In my `/api/v1/chats` `POST` route I make an async call to `user_chat_queries.addUserChat` for each `user_id` passed in the request body. The idea is that if lots of `user_id`'s come in I don't want to have each insertion `await`, instead I'd like to to dispatch all the insertions asynchronously so I do:

Asynchronous Route handler (https://github.com/caseysiebel/lang-exchange/blob/master/src/server/routes/chats.js#L57):

```
await Promise.all(user_ids.map((user_id) => {
    return user_chat_queries.addUserChat(user_id, chat.id)
}));
```

As opposed to,

Synchronously:

```
for (let user_id of user_ids) {
    await user_chat_queries.addUserChat(user_id, chat.id)
}
```

And in the `user_chat_queries` (https://github.com/caseysiebel/lang-exchange/blob/master/src/server/db/queries/user_chat.js#L5):

```
addUserChat: ( async (user_id, chat_id) => {
    const user_chat = await userChats
        .insert({ user_id, chat_id })
        .returning('*')
    const data = await db('user_chat').select('*')
    return user_chat;
}),
```

Now the route is accessed from my test file: (https://github.com/caseysiebel/lang-exchange/blob/master/test/routes.chats.test.js#L83)

```
it('should add 2 user_chats', (done) => {
    chai.request(server)
        .post('/api/v1/chats')
        .send({
            created_at: Date.now(),
            user_ids: [ 2, 4 ]
        })
        .end((err, res) => {
            should.not.exist(err);
            res.status.should.equal(201);
            res.type.should.equal('application/json');
            res.body.status.should.eql('success');
            const chat = res.body.data;
            chat.should.include.keys('id', 'created_at');

            knex('user_chat')
                .select('*')
                .then((data) => console.log('data', data))

            done();
        });
});
```

The log shows that the `{ user_id: 4, chat_id: 3 }` in inserted in the `user_chat` table twice.

The expected result (and the result when executed synchronously) is one `{ user_id: 2, chat_id: 3 }` record and one `{ user_id: 4, chat_id: 3 }` record are inserted into the `user_chat` table.

I can't track down what is causing this. It seems to me that `addUserChat` should insert a record made from the inputs it is passed each time, regardless of when it resolves.

Full code base: https://github.com/caseysiebel/lang-exchange

Debugging console output: https://gist.github.com/caseysiebel/262997efdd6467c72304ee783dadd9af#file-console-L5

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `mapSeries` type mechanism (Which is not available on default Promise API). So, you may need to use other 3rd party library like `bluebird`.

more details [bluebird mapSeries](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't show what `userChats` is in your code examples, but it looks like you may have a global instance of knex that you reuse across different queries, such as:

```
const userChats = knex('user_chats')
```

This is not safe because each query building operation mutates the query builder. You may get away with it if you're running in series but when you run in parallel, both your `addUserChat` calls are using the same `userChats` query builder at the same time and weird stuff happens.

Rule of thumb: call `knex()` once for every query you build.